# GLFW fast keyboard handling

Tags: glfw

How can I force GLFW to manage keyboard callback more than 60 times per second? That is, I want GLFW's keyboard handling speed to be dependent on actual fps. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

GLFW doesn't take control of the 'event loop' - so you might need to avoid `glfwWaitEvent`, and use `glfwPollEvent` in conjunction with `glfwSwapInterval(1)` if you want key event handling with each frame. Otherwise, you're probably wasting CPU/GPU.

```
glfwMakeContextCurrent(win);
glfwSwapInterval(1);

...

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(win))
{
    // ... redraw ...
    glfwSwapBuffers(win);

    ...

    glfwPollEvents(); // process pending events via callbacks.
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, that doesnt work for me. What should i do to make keyboard handling as fast as my program's render?